# Handling quotes in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I've got a line like this in my Blazor Web Assembly app:

```
<Calendar User="@context.User.Claims.Where(user => user.Type == "sid")"></Calendar>
```

But VS doesn't like the fact that "sid" is in quotes because it messes up the User="" attribute. How do I handle this?

Also, side question, is this the proper way to get a user Id in blazor web assembly? This seems like the easiest way, but I'm new to authentication so I don't know if I'm violating a best practice by doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use parenthesis between the @ and the C# code:

```
<Calendar User="@(context.User.Claims.Where(user => user.Type == "sid"))"></Calendar>
```

As to your second question, assuming you are using Asp.Net for your back end code, you can get the User object from the `HttpContext.Current.User` of the user request server side, you can read more about this here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I have been doing my binding without the double quotes lately. Looks cleaner but I'm not sure if it's making any difference. I can't find anything online to tell me but it works and definitely when using ( .. ). `<Calendar User=@(context.User.Claims.Where(user => user.Type == "sid"))></Calendar>`  That's just food for thought as a comment here.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks for your comment. Seems like a good way to do it. Hopefully they don't change things on you and require the outer quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use parenthesis `@( )` to make it a code block

```
<Calendar User="@(context.User.Claims.Where(user => user.Type == "sid"))" />
```